Winforms, open new form as top most
I have a simple Winforms application that I'm using to monitor a system. The main form is connected to a SignalR hub, and opens a form when receiving a message:
hubConnection.On("ReceiveMessage", (string aMessage) =>
{
    AlertMessageForm sAlertMessageForm = new AlertMessageForm(aMessage);
    sAlertMessageForm.TopMost = true;
    var sResult = sAlertMessageForm.ShowDialog(); 
});

This message is supposed to catch the users attention and open in front of the computers all open windows. The problem is, the AlertMessageForm SOMETIMES opens behind the all open windows, but most often it opens in front of all windows.
The main form is almost always hidden, using the Hide() method if that matters, but the problem seems to occur regardless if the main form is hidden or visible.
I've tried using TopMost = true, TopLevel = true, showing the form as a dialog. But it still opens behind all windows sometimes.

You simply cannot win this game in all cases, see what is a topmost window

You might try calling the form's Activate method in its Shown event handler. This might help in some instances, although it's a bit of an educated guess.

Try also calling BringToFront() in the shown event for the form.

@jmcilhinney Unfortunately didn't work :(

@JoelCoehoorn Also didn't work
